# Auto-number answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

When sharing a link to a stackoverflow question, we are always at a loss at how to mention the specific answers. So we end up referring to them by author name (hey how about that answer by Chris), or by number of upvotes (what about the answer with 43 votes).

Can the answers be numbered or labeled somehow right next to the upvote # so that they can easily be referred to? I realize one can just use the permalink to the answer, but if you are sharing the whole question and then discussing multiple answers, they are difficult to refer to in a conversation.

Or are we missing something obvious here?

Comment: They do have numbers. Click the share button below the answer and it's the first number in the URL (the second one is your user ID).

Comment: Well, generally there isn't more than one answer by a user to a question (although there's sometimes exceptions to this), so usernames should work in most cases.

Comment: Hmm… I don’t understand what the problem was with sharing multiple permalinks…?

Comment: Beware: if you're counting manually, then note that the order differs as per the sort order "active", "oldest" and "votes", and for the same number of votes are even sub-ordered randomly (if there's only one page of answers). So in many cases your numbering might not match someone else's numbering.

Comment: This is impractical. Answers get added. Answers get deleted. Answers get deleted and later restored. Further, if you're having conversations about multiple answers, I think you're missing the mission of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hey, I know! Let's not.

Answer (score 5):

Numbering an answer will encourage more "Fastest Gun In the West" answers.  This is where you post a short, incomplete, sometimes incorrect answer to ensure you place at the top of the list.  Then you go back in and edit the answer to make it complete / correct.

I think referring them to by author's name is adequate.

Comment: Note that my answer was first. :p

Comment: Note, I have no problem with people improving their answers, only those that game the system.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Noooooo

Answer (score 3):

User's display names are stable enough that I don't think there's any problem using that as the link title. It's also easier (for me anyways) to remember that some [answer was by Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190042/159251) than that it happened to be the *n*th posted.

Comment: All irrelevant if you just include the link.